# Remove dynamically created elements -> remove or just reload page

Tags: jquery

The click on a button creates a textarea, where you can then either "save" or "cancel".

This is not just the creation, but in involves some .html()-copying of other elements, replacing elements and so on.

Just by chance I didn't work on the cancel()-function and only had an empty `a href=""` on the "Cancel"-link, so when I click it, the page reloads and resets everything.

The page to reload is small and I wonder if I should bother removing the dynamically created element and other stuff involved with jquery or just let the page reload?

Comment: make your href="" to href="javascript:void(0);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the page is irrelevant, the cancel button should not reload the page, so don't do it. Using `.remove()` is trivial anyway :)

Comment: it's lazy resetting :)
it's not just remove() but it involves a couple of other things to do, but I wondered if I could take a shortcut

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the elements you are adding by adding a special class like *class="myclass createdByjQuery"* and later just call $(".createdByjQuery").remove()

http://api.jquery.com/remove/